# Knex.js - how to use max number of connections in pool

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling, knex.js, pool

I am using Knex.js with MySQL and would like to utilize a connection pool, as the test is under heavy load.

Even though I have set the `pool.max` to 10, I never see more than 1 connection being used. Here is an example that runs a query every 100ms:

```js
    const db = require("knex")({
      client: "mysql",
      connection: {
        user: "admin",
        password: "xx!",
        database: "xx",
        host: "xx",
        port: 3306,
      },
      debug: false,
      pool: {
        min: 2,
        max: 10,
      },
    });
    
    (async () => {
      setInterval(async () => {
        await db("titles").select(1).limit(1);
    
        console.log("numUsed", db.client.pool.numUsed());
        console.log("numFree", db.client.pool.numFree());
    
        console.log("--");
          }, 100);
        
        })();
```

When I run this I see the following:

```
numUsed 2
numFree 0
--
numUsed 2
numFree 0
--
numUsed 3
numFree 0
--
numUsed 2
numFree 1
--
numUsed 1
numFree 2
--
numUsed 1
numFree 3
--
numUsed 0
numFree 5
--
numUsed 1
numFree 4
--
numUsed 0
numFree 5
--
numUsed 0
numFree 5
--
numUsed 0
numFree 5
--
numUsed 0
numFree 5
```

We can see here the number used DOES increase to a max of 3 then reduces to 0. I dont understand this behavior and cannot find anything documented to explain.

Is there anything I should be doing to manually to force use of a pool resource?

I see in the [tarn.js](https://github.com/vincit/tarn.js/) docs (pool used my knex) there are methods to `acquire()` and `release()`. My expectation (given it is not documented) is that Knex manages this for me.

Appreciate any guidance.